# How to make the QueryString invisible in the AddressBar using SendRedirect()

Tags: servlets

I am calling a JSP page as the TargetURL from my servlet using the `sendRedirect()` as below:

`response.sendRedirect(TargetURL);`

Now 1.) I want the query String to be INVISIBLE in the address Bar.
2.) And my control is not going to the TargetPage(JSP page in my case) when i am using 
 response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(TargetURL));

Any suggessions with code snippets would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the functionality offered by [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29).

The primary difference between `forward()` and `sendRedirect()` is that the former will cause a new resource (a Servlet or JSP) to be invoked on the server while `sendRedirect()` will send a response to the client that will cause it to send a new request for the `TargetURL`.

The side effects of this are that with `sendRedirect()`, the user will see a change in the address since the client has been redirected; this doesn't happen with `forward()` since the change happens on the server and the client is not involved. Also, with `forward()`, the called resource gets the original request and response objects while with `sendRedirect()`, the client sends a whole new request so you'd lose any chance of sharing data via request attributes.